# <script> defer tag vs DOMContentLoaded vs DOMInteractive

Tags: javascript

If I would like to load a script, would the best practice be to use `defer`, `DOMContentLoaded` or `DOMInteractive`. I know that `defer`ed scripts are called just after `DOMInteractive`, so would there be any difference between them? Is one better practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It feels like microoptimization to me. Do you have any issue doing it with DOMContentLoaded? This probably really depends on what you're doing and you'd need to benchmark it if you were worried about it. I doubt it matters.

Comment: If it doesn't really matter, is one better practice? I've heard that you should only be putting markup related things in the HTML, and things to do with how the page is loaded should be put into the script itself.

Comment: So generally if you're going to get that granular it comes down to the script. What's it there for? Is there a benefit of initializing in a specific order of the process flow? Have you made any personal comparisons between strategies that lead to a more concise question? Currently it leaves a lot to opinion and guessing of use case.